# Scale i in SPIM

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I have this Spim Code and there is the Scale i,
What does it mean?

```
.Data
a:            .word -2,35,-8,12-3,-62,-41
n:            .word 7
endl:         .asciiz "\n"

 .text

main:

        li $t0, 0        #i
        li $t1, 0        #Npos
        li $t1, 0        #Nneg
        lw $s0, n        # $s0 = n

Start:

        bge $t0, $s1, Finish
        mul $t3, $t0, 4    **#scale i**
        lw $4, a($t3)      # load a[i] into $t4
```

Comment: It multiplies i by 4, because addresses use bytes and a word is 4 bytes.

Comment: It's a comment on the mul instruction.

Comment: I mean.. if the $t3 is 0 why will I multiplies it bei 4?

Comment: It looks like a loop, you just didn't paste the end. Control comes back to `Start` and t0 is no longer zero at that point.